# Declaring 2D array in C only knowing length of one

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working in C and am trying to declare a 2D array while only knowing one length (I only know how many "rows" initially, not how many "columns"). I know to declare a normal array without knowing initial size doing

```
int *rows = null;
```

And a later call to

```
rows = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

will work, but is is there something similar I could do for a 2D array?

Comment: Hint: a 2d array is nothing more than a 1d array of pointers.

Comment: Or... it's internally a contiguous buffer that encompasses the entire area of the 2D array and does multiplication to find the index instead of a 2nd pointer dereference.  2+D arrays in C are interesting.

Comment: @bishop — not really; a 2D array is not a 1D array of pointers.  If you write `int array[3][4];`, then there isn't a 1D array of pointers lurking in the storage.  There are 12 contiguously allocated `int` memory locations.  True, `array[0]` becomes an `int *` in many contexts, but its type is formally `int (*)[4]` — pointer to an array of 4 `int`, but there is no memory location holding the address of `array[0]`.

Comment: @bishop: An array of pointers may be part of the answer — but that isn't the same as a 2D array.  And yes, if you have a pointer to a pointer, you can use `ptr[i][j]` (double subscript) notation to access element `j` of row `i` of the data accessed via `ptr`.  That still doesn't make it a 2D array.

Comment: How are you going to know how many columns there are in each row, Joe?  Are all rows going to have the same number of columns?  Does each row have its own size?  You could use `int **rows = NULL;` and then subsequently allocate `rows = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(*rows));` to allocate enough pointers for `num_rows` rows.  Then for each row you'd need to allocate the right number of columns.  Ragged arrays are trickier than rectangular arrays (uniform number of columns).  Etc.  And if you need a rectangular array, you can wait until you know the rows and columns and then make one allocation.

Comment: Well you have to know the number of columns sooner or later, why dont' you wait on declaring the array until that number is known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my Example give you 2 idea alloc 2d array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    //Example Ar_2D[20][50] from alloc
    //method 1
    int i;
    int **Ar_2D=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*20);

    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        Ar_2D[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);
    }
    //----------------------do everything you want with Ar_2D[20][50]
    //using this method cause below
    //&(Ar_2D[0][49])+1 != &(Ar_2D[1][0]) means not always == if you are luck will ==
    if(&(Ar_2D[0][49])+1 != &(Ar_2D[1][0])){
        printf("you are right about Ar_2D!\n");
    }


    //----------------------Release memory alloc
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        free(Ar_2D[i]);
    }
    free(Ar_2D);

    //----------------------

    //Example Ar_2D_M2[20][50] from alloc
    //method 2
    int **Ar_2D_M2=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*20);
    int *Ar_1D=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*50*20);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        Ar_2D_M2[i]=&(Ar_1D[i*50]);
    }
    //----------------------do everything you want with Ar_2D_M2[20][50]
    //using this method cause below
    //&(Ar_2D_M2[0][49])+1 == &(Ar_2D_M2[1][0])  always == 
    if(&(Ar_2D_M2[0][49])+1 == &(Ar_2D_M2[1][0])){
        printf("you are right about Ar_2D_M2!\n");
    }

    //----------------------Release memory alloc
    free(Ar_1D);
    free(Ar_2D_M2);
    return 0;
}
```

Method 2 will give you

1 2 3... 20

21 ..... 40

41 ..... 60

...

nice order(ponter) in 2d array

3D 4D 5D is like this build from 1D